# Making a function globally available in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In previous project I had this function defined in AppDeligate.m and it was globally available to all the parts of the app:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Now for some reason when I place this code in a new project, only the specific class can see the function, but the child classes do not see it.

How do I make this function globally available?

Comment: No you didn't, unless you did `#import "AppDelegate.m"`, and I'm sure you didn't do that...

Comment: Usually using pre-processor macros isn't a good practice. On your place I would make it a function within UIColor category. If you want to stay with macro for speed reasons, you can put it into category file as well and use that file wherever you use it in your project. However macros are very difficult to maintain and debug afterwards. This is why I would make it fully functional category method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the file to YOURPROJECTNAME-Prefix.pch, it will be added as a precompiled header, and available in all your code-files.

Comment: Right... you mean to put the #define code inside Prefix.pch... Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I usually create separate files for Model-objects, constants, and macros (depending on how big the project is) and import them in the prefix.pch along with the frameworks that I need throughout the application.

Answer (score 7):

You can define your macro in the `.pch` file of your project, but it's generally a bad idea, since it will produce code which is difficult to read, maintain and debug.

In your specific case I'd rather create a category on `UIColor`.

Here's a implementation with extra stuff which may come in handy.

### UIColor+Extra.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Extra)
+ (instancetype)extra_colorWith255BasedRed:(NSUInteger)red green:(NSUInteger)green blue:(NSUInteger)blue;
+ (instancetype)extra_colorWith255BasedRed:(NSUInteger)red green:(NSUInteger)green blue:(NSUInteger)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;
+ (instancetype)extra_colorWithHex:(NSInteger)hex;

@end
```

### UIColor+Extra.m

```
#import "UIColor+Extra.h"

@implementation UIColor (Extra)

+ (instancetype)extra_colorWith255BasedRed:(NSUInteger)red green:(NSUInteger)green blue:(NSUInteger)blue {
    return [self colorWith255BasedRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}

+ (instancetype)extra_colorWith255BasedRed:(NSUInteger)red green:(NSUInteger)green blue:(NSUInteger)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    return [self colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha];
}

+ (instancetype)extra_colorWithHex:(NSInteger)hex {
    return [UIColor colorWith255BasedRed:((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) green:((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) blue:(hex & 0xFF)];
}

@end
```

Then just place

```
#import "UIColor+Extra.h"
```

in your `.pch` file and use it elsewhere.

### Examples

```
UIColor * cyan = [UIColor extra_colorWithHex:0x00FFFF];
UIColor * magenta = [UIColor extra_colorWith255BasedRed:255 green:0 blue:255];
```

Comment: It's recommended that when you add a category to a system class, to put a prefix on it just in case a method of the same name gets added to the class in the future.

Comment: So why is this better than #define in Prefix.pch?

Comment: @user1615362 as Sulthan said, it's more readable, maintainable, idiomatic and it looks like a native method on `UIColor`, therefore it's nicer under many point of views. I'd say it is a perfect showcase for the use of categories.

Comment: not to mention that debugging macros is a hell, so you really don't want have a lot of them around in your code base.

Answer (score 0):

Audun Kjelstrup has the best answer.

You also have the option to setup a static method inside a class.

```
+ (UIColor *)UIColorFromRGB {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gabriele about macros (undesirable as functions) and that what you are trying to do would be nice/appropriate in a category. However, I also want to point out that Objective-C can also do C-style functions (as opposed to the macro that you have shown).

For example:

```
// Header
UIColor * UIColorFromRGB(NSInteger rgbValue);

// Implementation
UIColor * UIColorFromRGB(NSInteger rgbValue)
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: ((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
                           green: ((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
                            blue: ((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```